# How to view starting and ending address of memory segments like stack, data, heap and code?

Tags: linux, memory

As the memory segments are part of Linux operating system, is it possible to view their respective addresses using simple C program or any linux commands.

Comment: It sounds like you may want to try using a debugger. `gdb` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wrote a program and you want to see its memory mapping when it's running, you can run it in a debugger like `gdb`, then start it, and take a look at the memory map with the command `info proc mappings`, the output will be something like this:

```
(gdb) info proc mappings
process 6520
Mapped address spaces:

    Start Addr   End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
       0x10000    0x15000     0x5000        0x0 /bin/true
       0x24000    0x25000     0x1000     0x4000 /bin/true
       0x25000    0x26000     0x1000     0x5000 /bin/true
    0x76e6e000 0x76f98000   0x12a000        0x0 /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.24.so
    ... etc ...
    0x7efdf000 0x7f000000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]
    0xffff0000 0xffff1000     0x1000        0x0 [vectors]
```

If you instead want to see the mappings of an already running process you can, assuming that you have the right permissions, do `cat /proc/<pid>/maps`. In alternative you could attach to the process with `gdb -p <pid>` and do what I explained above.

Comment: 0x7efdf000 0x7f000000    0x21000        0x0 [stack]. Small query here. Does this address range refers only the particular process or the whole operating system's stack.

Comment: There's no such thing as "the whole operating system stack". Each process has its own stack mapped in its virtual memory space.

Comment: Ok got ur point. I was not aware of virtual memory concepts. So i got confused little bit earlier.